# How do I change the width and height of a drawableRight image?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-studio

I am trying to set an image right next to the radio button but the image is too large that it covers the whole thing basically.

[This is what I'm ending up with currently](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3UgId.png)

```
<RadioButton
                android:layout_height="20dp"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:drawableRight="@drawable/incorrect_img"
                android:id="@+id/q3_wrong1"
                android:text="@string/q3_choice1" />
```

Comment: what size of image are you using?

Comment: I'm using a 512 x 512 image

Comment: that's why.. try to resize it to atleast 64x64 or 48x48

Comment: So there's no other way to edit an image's width and height using android studio other than using ImageView?

Comment: yes that's correct. btw, why do yu want to put 512x512?

Comment: I downloaded the image without editing the size since I thought there would be a way to change the width and height of the image like an ImageView in the RadioButton view. But yeah, I'll be changing it to 64x64, Thanks Mikee!

Comment: try my answer ty

Comment: you have to resize it there is no other way till now

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

<RadioButton
 android:id="@id/rb_1"
 android:layout_width="wrap_content"
 android:layout_height="wrap_content"
/>

<ImageView
 android:layout_width="your width"
 android:layout_height="your height"
/>

</LinearLayout>
```

the output will be :
 [image]

Comment: I have a vertical RadioGroup though that's why I'm using the drawableRight feature to add my image right next to the button instead of ImageView.

Comment: Ok, then try to resize the image :)